# Printing a Bootstrap website

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, printing

I created my resume using bootstrap distributed the column into 3 and 9. The first 3 columns are all the skills and the 9 columns are my work experience.  Now when it is time to convert the webpage into a pdf format (the employer wants it in pdf a4 sized) the bootstrap kinda combined the columns. I have the code below

Also the anchor tag is showing the page it is linking to? I just want it to look exactly like the webpage. So the employer can click on the href link and go to the website.

Someone recommended to use col-sm-*. I am already using that and it doesn't quite look right.

Here is the code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Hi Hello</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <style>
    body {
        padding-top: 70px;
        /* Required padding for .navbar-fixed-top. Remove if using .navbar-static-top. Change if height of navigation changes. */
    }


    h1 { 
     }

     .greybackground{

     }

     .content{
        color:  #505050;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
        font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;

     }

     .skills{
     }



     .heading2{
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: bold;
     }


     .company{
        /*font-style: italic;*/
        text-align:right;
     }

     .heading{
        color:  #909090;
     }

     .job-title{
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: bold;
     }


     .techused{
        font-style: italic;
        color:  #909090;

     }

     .contact{
        text-align:right;
     }

    </style>
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


</head>

<body>
    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container content">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-7">
               <h1> Hello </h1>

            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-5 heading contact" >
                Website :<a href="http://www.google.com" >Lin </a>
                <br>
                GitHub :<a href="https://google.com" >jj</a>
                <br>
                LinkedIn : <a href="https://www.google.com">likka</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3"> 
                <div class="heading heading2">  <i class="fa fa-wrench "></i> SKILL SET </div>
                <hr>
                <div class="skills">
                    PROGRAMMING
                    <ul>
                        <li> Java </li>
                        <li> C++ </li>
                        <li> C </li>
                        <li> RobotC </li>
                    </ul>

                    <br>

                    WEB DEVELOPMENT

                    <ul>
                        <li> JavaScript</li>
                        <li> HTML/CSS </li>
                        <li> PHP </li>
                    </ul>

                    <br>

                    DATABASE

                    <ul>
                        <li> SQL</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <hr>
                <div class="heading heading2">  <i class="fa fa-wrench "></i> EDUCATION </div>
                <hr>
                <div class="skills">
                    Hello
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <div class="heading heading2"> <i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i>  WORK EXPERIENCE </div>
                <hr>
                <div class="row ">

                    <div class="position col-sm-8 job-title" >Software and Web Developer</div> 
                    <div class="company col-sm-4"><img src="" style="height:16px;width:8px;"> kkk</div>

                    <div class="col-sm-12 greybackground">
                        <ul>
                            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. </li>

                        </ul>

                        <div class="techused">Technologies used : Java , JavaFX , SQL , JDBC , Selenium , JavaScript , jQuery , PHP </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="row ">

                    <div class="position col-sm-8 job-title" >Infrastruture Security Analyst</div> 
                    <div class="company col-sm-4"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/53/Maple_Leaf_Foods.svg" style="height:20px;width:20px;"> Maple Leaf Foods</div>

                    <div class="col-sm-12 greybackground">
                        <ul>
                            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.  </li>
                        </ul>

                         <div class="techused"> Technologies used : Microsoft's SCCM, Cisco's IronPort , FireEye and ePo.</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr>
                <div class="heading heading2"> <i class="fa fa-code"></i> PROJECTS</div>
                <hr>
                <div class="row ">

                    <div class="position col-sm-8 job-title" >Hello</div> 
                    <div class="company col-sm-4"><img src="http://hackthenorth.com/img/logo.png" style="height:15px;width:15px;"> Hack the North</div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 greybackground">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                Won top pebble award at Canada's largest Hackathon by developing a Nocturnal epilepsy tracker and prevention pebble application.
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                Worked as a pair programmer on the Pebble and Android Platforms to capture, store and send information to a server database for further data analytics
                            </li>
                        </ul>

                        <div class="featured">Featured On : <a href="https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8372583">Hacker News</a>, <a href="http://challengepost.com/software/pebilepsy"> Challenge Post</a> , <a href="http://www.medgadget.com/2014/09/pebilepsy-uses-fitness-tracker-to-monitor-night-time-seizures.html" > Med Gadgets </a></div>
                        <div class="techused">Technologies used : Android Development, Pebble API </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="position col-sm-8 job-title" >Game Robot</div> 
                    <div class="company col-sm-4"></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 greybackground">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                Built a joystick-controlled robot which could retrive objects.
                            </li>
                        </ul>

                        <div class="techused"> Technologies used : RobotC , NXT Mindstorm Robot</div>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <br>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="position col-sm-8 job-title" >Temperature Map</div> 
                    <div class="company col-sm-4"></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 greybackground">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                               Allows the user to browse map and retrive the current time and temperature of the location the user picks. 
                            </li>
                        </ul>

                        <div class="techused"> Technologies used : Google Map API , Temperature API , jQuery , AJAX</div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <br>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="position col-sm-8 job-title" >Exam Schedular</div> 
                    <div class="company col-sm-4"></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 greybackground">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                Allows a UW Student to view their exam schedule and add it to google calendar.
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="techused"> Technologies used :  jQuery , AJAX</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
             </div>

        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->

    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->

    <!-- jQuery Version 1.11.1 -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You might be encountering http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support-printing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change this line:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

to

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print">
```

so your printer can read Bootstrap styles. Same goes for your internal styles (try using an external style sheet!).

If you want these styles to be used by both printing and web, then use

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
```

You can read [more about *media types* here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/media.html#media-sheets)

Comment: But this kinda spoils my overall layout? :(

Comment: I want the two columns is it possible to get that?

Comment: yes, this should work straight as it is, and it won't change your layout if you add `media="all"` . Basically, you're using the media types to tell both the browser and the printer to read the CSS stylesheet. If you don't do this, the pinter will ignore it. Take a read to the link I posted for a better and more complete explanation.